# Python OOP: Automatically changing instances of a class after changing a class attribute?

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class Employee:
    pay_raise_percent = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    

p1 = Employee('John', 50_000)
p2 = Employee('Alex', 75_000)
p3 = Employee('Caleb', 90_000)

Employee.pay_raise_percent = 1.04
print(p1.salary, p2.salary, p3.salary, sep='\n')
# 52000 78000 93600
```

is it possible to make it so that changing a class attribute leads to an automatic increase in the salary of all instances by this value without doing that explicitly for each of them?

Comment: `pay_raise_percent` doesn't really make sense as a class attribute. Rather, a method like `Employee.get_raise` should take a percentage as an *argument*, and modify that instance's salary.

Comment: in that case how would you implement it as a method?

Comment: Something like `def give_raise(self, pct): self.salary *= (1 + pct/100)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like an excellent use case for [properties](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property). Properties look like ordinary instance variables but act like methods. Consider

```
class Employee:
  pay_raise_percent = 1.00

  def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self._salary = salary # "Private" variable

  @property
  def salary(self):
    return self._salary * Employee.pay_raise_percent

p1 = Employee('John', 50_000)
print(p1.salary) # 50000
Employee.pay_raise_percent = 1.04
print(p1.salary) # 52000
```

In reality, every access to `p1.salary` is calling a method that does some math on the *real* field `p1._salary`, so any updates to `Employee.pay_raise_percent` will be seen whenever the salary is requested.